# OSX Web Browsers Won't Load a Page

Tags: safari, wifi, google-chrome, performance

I have a 2013 27" iMac running 10.15.3 and for some recent over the past couple weeks if I leave my computer idle for several hours (usually 12+) when I get back to my desktop none of my web browsers will load ANY page (Safari, Chrome, Brave - same results). The odd part is if I have Messages open or Find My Friends, those apps work fine and load new data. If I open Terminal I can PING a URL and get a perfect response back.

If I try to restart my computer I will get messages that an app is no responding and although the mouse / keyboard continue to work the computer will appear non responsive to new apps opening or closing. I am on a wifi connection but always a strong signal.

I have run a diagnostics check (hold D during startup) and it reported back no issues. I ran a disk utility scan - also no issues. I checked for malware and antivirus - also clear. Nothing jumps out in the console logs. The only way for me to get the web browsers to work is to force restart the whole mac which is very frustrating.

Any thoughts on what could be happening?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried restarting the browser(s)?

Comment: "an app is no responding" … which app? Check in Activity Monitor before attempting to restart.

Comment: Tried restarting all browsers and reinstalling the browsers that I could reinstall.

Comment: The browsers become not responsive.